# convert curl line command in php code

Tags: php, curl

can anyone help me to convert that curl comand line in a php curl code ? plz

curl -v --data "WSCommunityStringRW?2=1200ve50set&Submit=Submit" http://xxxxx/123 -u "admin:a1s2d3" --anyauth

---

Yes.I did something but ... not work :(

```
$api_url  = 'xxx/123';
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:a1s2d3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'WSCommunityStringRW?2' => '1200ve50set',
    'Submit' => 'Submit'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at the [cURL pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in the PHP manual? It should contain everything you need for this.

**Edit**

In the code you've provided, [curl_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) is missing. If it doesn't work after calling `curl_exec()`, try looking at the output of [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).